# Start jest in watch mode without executing any tests

Tags: jestjs

I have a lot of test files in my project, and I would like to know **how can I start jest in watch mode without executing any tests automatically?**

Because, as of now, when I start jest in watch mode it starts executing some long-running tests from many **.spec.ts** files, and I don't want that. I just want to start it, and wait for me to enter regex to filer files or whatever.

Comment: Hello Ruslan, Do you want to run Only some specific tests?

Comment: No, I don't want to run any tests at wall, just enter watch mode and wait for my commands. For now, I just use `jest "impossible-regex"` command because there is no file called `impossible-regex` in my repo)

Comment: Running in watch mode will run existing tests, then wait for module changes and reexecute tests in the changed modules only (thus speeding feedback).  You might need to split your tests into suites if your total test project size is long-running, so you can concentrate on only the pertinent parts.  You might then consider long-running tests as part of a Continuous Integration process.